Why doesn't Fedora 40 recognize USB 3.0 ports on Gigabyte motherboard?
I have Fedora 40 installed on a desktop with motherboard GA-990FXA-UD3-rev-40. It seems to be working fine, except for the USB 3.0 ports which don't appear to be recognized at all. The USB 2.0 ports seem to work fine, but the same USB+M.2 or USB+SATA adapters that I use for connecting SSD drives do not work when plugged into the USB 3.0 (blue) ports.
I've run dnf update plenty of times, and the current kernel info is:
Linux fedora 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Aug 19 14:09:30 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

In the BIOS's, I have the following settings:

IOMMU = Enabled.
XHCI = Enabled
EHCI = Enabled

My grub looks like
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau rhgb quiet amd_iommu=on"

I've tried adding "iommu=soft", but that doesn't seem to have any effect.
I've also tried searching through the journal, but I'm not sure what exactly to look for.
Not sure if this helps:
[root@fedora ~]# sudo modprobe xhci_hcd
[root@fedora ~]# lsmod | grep xhci_hcd
[root@fedora ~]#
[root@fedora ~]# dmesg | grep -i usb
[    0.541548] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.541567] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.541574] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.541587] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.026990] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.082942] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.10
[    1.082946] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.082949] usb usb1: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[    1.082950] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 ohci_hcd
[    1.082952] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.0
[    1.083092] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.083502] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.089839] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.089908] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.10
[    1.089911] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.089913] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.089915] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 ehci_hcd
[    1.089916] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.2
[    1.090028] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.141891] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.142117] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.148833] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.148903] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.10
[    1.148909] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.148911] usb usb3: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.148913] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 ehci_hcd
[    1.148914] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.2
[    1.149035] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.149263] ehci-pci 0000:00:16.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.155833] ehci-pci 0000:00:16.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.155897] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.10
[    1.155900] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.155902] usb usb4: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.155904] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 ehci_hcd
[    1.155907] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:16.2
[    1.156053] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.156238] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    1.211920] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.10
[    1.211924] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.211927] usb usb5: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[    1.211928] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 ohci_hcd
[    1.211930] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.0
[    1.212048] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.212359] ohci-pci 0000:00:14.5: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    1.267889] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.10
[    1.267893] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.267896] usb usb6: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[    1.267897] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 ohci_hcd
[    1.267899] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.5
[    1.268018] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.268282] ohci-pci 0000:00:16.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 7
[    1.323909] usb usb7: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 6.10
[    1.323913] usb usb7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.323915] usb usb7: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[    1.323917] usb usb7: Manufacturer: Linux 6.10.6-200.fc40.x86_64 ohci_hcd
[    1.323918] usb usb7: SerialNumber: 0000:00:16.0
[    1.324046] hub 7-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.324512] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[   30.996315] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: USB bus 8 deregistered
[   30.996462] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   30.996469] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   31.002235] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   31.002239] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   31.239061] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
[   31.408058] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b, bcdDevice=24.10
[   31.408071] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   31.408077] usb 1-2: Product: USB Receiver
[   31.408082] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[   31.416449] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:046D:C52B.0001/input/input2
[   31.468503] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input0
[   31.473577] input: Logitech USB Receiver Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:046D:C52B.0002/input/input3
[   31.473743] input: Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:046D:C52B.0002/input/input4
[   31.525379] input: Logitech USB Receiver System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:046D:C52B.0002/input/input5
[   31.525497] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0002: input,hiddev96,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input1
[   31.529616] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev97,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input2
[   36.947746] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input2
[   37.060030] input: Logitech Wireless Device PID:404d Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:404D.0004/input/input7
[   37.062398] input: Logitech Wireless Device PID:404d Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:404D.0004/input/input8
[   37.062560] hid-generic 0003:046D:404D.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Device PID:404d] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input2:1
[   37.180519] input: Logitech K400 Plus as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:404D.0004/input/input12
[   37.180849] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:404D.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech K400 Plus] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input2:1
[   88.819109] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   88.949713] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   88.949724] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[   88.949728] usb 3-4: Product: ASMT1051
[   88.949732] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: asmedia
[   88.949734] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 123456791727
[   88.972015] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   88.976950] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[428387.837787] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[497134.378631] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[497134.518625] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=9210, bcdDevice=20.01
[497134.518638] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[497134.518644] usb 2-2: Product: SSK Storage
[497134.518649] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: SSK
[497134.518653] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 012345678913
[497134.556820] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[497134.557352] scsi host10: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[526258.001644] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
[root@fedora ~]#

How do I troubleshoot this?

Have you seen tips on Mint: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=266630 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143433? E.G. In the BIOS, set IOMMU to "Enabled".

I have this board and can confirm that @DrMoishePippik's tip will work, both in Linux Mint and Arch.

And if it doesn't, while keeping IOMMU enabled, add the kernel boot parameter iommu=soft...

I've updated the description to add that IOMMU is enabled in the bios, and I have "amd_iommu=on" in /etc/default/grub.    I've tried "iommu=soft" in the grub, but that doesn't seem to work either.
